# Передать значение переменной из js в php

Tags: javascript

Есть javascript код с переменной, в которой содержится результат, в зависимости от него хочу выводить часть кода (HTML + PHP). 
Думая, пришел к выводу, что нужно как то передать переменную из js в php, что бы потом на PHP делать условия if else и выводить что нужно. Так как с PHP более удобно это делать, и можно к примеру делать так

```
<? if(1=1) { ?>
Сдесь любой код
<? } ?>
```

На js пока что не придумал как такое можно реализовать.
Думаю это возможно сделать с помощью Ajax, но если есть какой то другой более простой и подходящий способ, рад буду знать.

Comment: ajax то что надо, пили rest запросы да и все

Answer (score -1):

Я иногда делаю так:

```
JS: 
var count = <?php echo $param; ?>
if (count > 2) {
    alert(count);
} else {
    *some_code*
}
```

Не знаю, насколько тут большой уровень костыльности, но при простых задачах легче, чем AJAX'ом подгружать данные

---

Извиняюсь, неправильно понял вопрос